# Can I use Expo to run a react-native project created by RN CLI?

Tags: react-native, expo

I was wondering if I could use Expo to run the react-native project that I created using the `npx react-native init` command, since it generates a better structure for real-world applications.

The reason I want to do this is to avoid the countless erros that I had while running and debugging the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that..
React native and expo are different.

You can run expo projects on react native by detaching them. Expo has limitations.

You can not run react native projects on expo, i.e projects made by react native init/npx can't run on expo

Comment: I guess I will detach mu current expo project.Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a package made available by the expo

> react-native-unimodules

for any React Native project using some resources made available by the expo.

[react-native-unimodules](https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow :). I think that is an interesting package. The only thing is i am not sure that answers the question being how to run react native with expo